# css not being applied ".class" over "> div" tag

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

I have below CSS and I want to change the color in div to blue if it matches a certain class,

I tried following but it dint work

```
&__header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    .list-row__statAG {
      color: #315ec5; ///this is not applied 
      border-bottom: 1px solid #315ec5;
      height: 80px;
    }
    .list-row__scTG {
      color: #315ec5; ///this is not applied 
      border-bottom: 1px solid #315ec5;
      height: 80px;
    }
    &>div {
      text-align: left !important;
      color: #B9BABD !important; ////it is using this color -----How can I override this ?

    }
  }
```

I have also tried making the following change but it only works for 2nd element , can I add not condition for a class like  ***div:not('.list-row__scTG','.list-row__statAG')***

```
  &>div:not(:nth-last-of-type(2)) {
```

Comment: What's your override supposed to be? `&.class > div` or `& > div.class`? You as assigning the color with `!important` which is going to be an issue, most likely. Also, to chain `not()` you can't list them in a single selector for now (it's coming), you'd need to do `div:not(.list-row__scTG):not(.list-row__statAG)`.

Comment: thanks color: #B9BABD !important; <--- removing this !important worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
&__header {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;

.list-row__statAG {
  color: #315ec5 !important; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #315ec5;
  height: 80px;
}
.list-row__scTG {
  color: #315ec5 !important; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #315ec5;
  height: 80px;
}
&>div {
  text-align: left !important;
  color: #B9BABD !important; 

}
```

}